# VBA: How to add columns to all the formula cell references in a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have a sheet, named for example `Calculations 1`, filled with formulas and every formula is using data from 1 column (say column A), `Data Column 1`, in another sheet `Data`.

What I want is to add another data column (say in column C), `Data Column 2`, in the `Data` sheet and copy my `Calculations 1` sheet (named `Calculations 2`) and make every formula reference the new `column C`.

I know how to write code to copy the sheet, to insert a the new column but I'm stuck in how to make every formula in the new calculations sheet to reference the new data column. The rows and formulas remain unchanged.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide examples of the formulas and the things you have already done to make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not completely understand the question, but if the formulas are written with a "$"  in them. This causes that when you add or remove columns / rows the formulas will be linked to the original location. e.g. $A1 --> the A will be locked. the 1 is variable. A$1 --> A is variable, the 1 is locked.

But because the header says VBA, maybe the question is how to change the formulas by vba. This can be done using a macro.

With the macro loop through all the cells and change the formula.

This can be done bij

```
Range("cell position").Formula = "formula"
```

Example:

```
Range("B16").Formula = "=A1+B1"
```